# write small files in hdfs or use coalesce

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using sql spark to read and write files in hdfs, using the following code:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("D:/resources/input/address/year_month_day=2018-07-02")
val df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("D:/resources/output/t_kcdo_person")
```

the result of writing are many small
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evYlg.png)
. According to what I am learning, it is not recommended that the files have a size smaller than 128 MB. I was looking for ways to have fewer files but with larger size and I found the function df.coalesce, but I have a question if it is advisable to use this function because it would be avoiding parallelism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Spark. Every partition would output one file regardless to the actual size of the data. `coalesce` is not a silver bullet either - you need to be very careful about the new number of partitions -  too small and the application will OOM. You might consider calculating the coalesce value on runtime, but in most cases that would mean persisting the data to disk, get the actual size, and read again and `coalesce` to the optimal size.

In your simple example you can get the actual input size beforehand. But for the general case, there are tools like [FileCrush](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/filecrush) that operate on your output (small files) and merges them to fewer files. But its old now and based on map-reduce (still works though). In my team we built a very simple Spark version of that, and you can easily create your own. If you do, remember to consider comperssion codecs when you calculate the optimal number of partitions.

Also, you are correct about worrying about parallelism when using `coalesce`. If this becomes an issue, and you have some calculations that should run on a higher level of parallelism before the `coalesce`, you can use something like `spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)` to create a new dataframe and avoid getting the `coalesce` pushed down too low. However this has important implications that you need to consider.